# Find orthonormal basis using mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

normalized eigenvector $u_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ need to find orthonormal basis of $Span[{u_1}]^
⊥$  using mathematica.
I tried with ***Orthogonalize*** command and did not work.

Comment: You mean `Cross[1/Sqrt[5] {1, Sqrt[2]}]`?

Comment: Actually, I was going to solve Schur Decomposition. I could do that using `SchurDecomposition[N[{{7, -2}, {12, -3}}]]` in Mathematica Software. But I want to do that using different method.

Comment: Extending from a vector to a basis can be done with `NullSpace`. Then orthogonalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the span of $u_1$ is the same as the span of `{1,2}`, you could simply do this:

1. Find some vector orthogonal to `{1,2}`:

   ```
       v1 = {1, 2}
       Solve[{x, y} . v1 == 0}]
   (* {{y -> - x/2}} *)
   ```
2. Accordingly, take say `x -> 2` in that solution and then `y -> -1`. Thus set:

   ```
       v2 = {2, -1}
   ```
3. Thus `v2` is in the 1-dimensional space orthogonal to the span of your $u_1$. Now just normalize `v2`.